# Background moves from centered to left when I scroll down the page, how can I keep it centered while scrolling?

Tags: jquery, css, background, scroll, center

I have a gif that I'm using for a background and its centered when the page first loads.  When I start to scroll the website the gif moves to the far left and is never centered again.  I'm thinking that I'm missing a css style that can keep the background fixed when scrolling.  It also might be my jQuery parallax function that keeps pushing it to the left.

Below is the code that I'm using

//html

```
 <section class="box slide slide-1">
    <div class="container">
    <!--  <h1>Main Title</h1> -->
    </div>
  </section>
```

//css

```
section.box.slide {
padding: 240px 0;
background-position: 0 0;
/*  background-position: center;*/
}

section.box.slide h1 {
color: yellow;
font-size: 48px;
/*line-height: 1;*/
font-weight: 700;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}

section.box.slide-1 {
border: 1px solid white;
background: #D80000 url("../gif/lRoomWhiteRed.gif") no-repeat;
background-position: center;

 /* background-attachment: fixed;*/
 /* background-size: cover*/
 }
```

//jQuery for parallax

```
(function(){
 var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
  speed = .3;

 window.onscroll = function(){
 [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(p,i){

  var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
      theBackgroundPos = "0 " + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";

  p.style.backgroundPosition = theBackgroundPos;
  });
  };
 })();
```

Comment: I would assume its your parallax...

Comment: the parallax offsets the Y on the window, which is why this is confusing me because I would think to offset the center I would have to be offsetting the X on the page.  Maybe increase the 0 in theBackgroundPos= "0" + windowYoffset ??

Comment: ok it is the parallax - changed the 0 value to centered and its centering the images on scroll -  Would it be possible to change the jQuery to only center scroll the first background and not the other ones?

Answer (score 1):

I think the jQuery is affecting all the elements with `.slide` class. Maybe try to remove this class on your gif and position it in the other ways.